# How to use xml_parse_into_struct()

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a am trying to use `xml_parse_into_struct()`, but it is returning false

My code looks like this

```
$p = xml_parser_create();
if (xml_parse_into_struct($p,$contenido,$vals, $index))
{
    print_r($vals);
}
```

the content of variable

`$contenido`
looks like this

```
<saltest31>
    <anuncio1>
        <id>12346</id>
        <titulo> BD authority</titulo>
        <descripcion>Preciosa casa en jardines de las animas, en xalapa veracruz. 550 m2 de terreno la mayoria jardin con arboles frutales, amplias recamaras, cocina, salon de juegos, terraza y palapa CVICA123</descripcion>
        <fecha>11/12/2014 10:27:15</fecha>
        <municipio>Chalchuapa</municipio>
        <moneda>Peso</moneda>
        <construccion>500</construccion>
        <terreno>550</terreno>
        <habitaciones>5</habitaciones>
        <banos>4</banos>
        <imagenes>
                <TOTAL>10</TOTAL>
                <IDIMAGE>5567</imagen_url>
                <IDIMAGE>5568</imagen_url>
                <IDIMAGE>5569</imagen_url>
                <IDIMAGE>5570</imagen_url>
                <IDIMAGE>5571</imagen_url>
        </imagenes>
    </anuncio>
</saltest3>
```

My problem is that the if statement is not returning true , Any idea where I am going wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have too many mis-matched tags in your XML starting right at the top with `<saltest31>...</saltest3>`. This will cause a 0 to be returned.

In addition `xml_parse_into_struct()` returns a 1 or a 0 which really shouldn't be mistaken for true and false. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php),

> xml_parse_into_struct() returns 0 for failure and 1 for success. This is not the same as **FALSE** and **TRUE**, be careful with operators such as ===.

Given that, you should perform the test explicitly:

```
$p = xml_parser_create();
if (xml_parse_into_struct($p,$contenido,$vals, $index) == 1)
{
    print_r($vals);
}
```